# Freebusy google API not getting returned with or w/o a key

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

As can be seen, Ihave read/write access to google calendar (sensitive scope). I want to also have access to freebusy scope of google calendar (not sensitive).

I followed the same steps but just provided a written justification instead of video as it's not sensitive as only sensitive scopes require one. Nonetheless, I am not getting granted permission nor are there any signs that's even being processed as it's been weeks. What shall I do?

I only see this on my dashboard which is for the other scope & feel like is the reason why the new scope is not getting reviewed despite my resubmission.

[image]

I know I have not been approved as the green check isn't displayed beside freebusy unlike auth/calendar
[image]

Currently, when I call the API:

Code:

```
def busyTimes():
    """
    returns busy time of the user in a day
    """
    body = {
    "timeMin":datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat(),
    "timeMax": '2021-03-27T21:27:58.945714-04:00',
        "items": [
        {
        "id": "....@group.calendar.google.com"
        }
    ]
    }
req = requests.post(url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy', data = body) 
req_ = req.json()
return str(req_)
```

I would get:

```
{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The request is missing a valid API key.', 'errors': [{'message': 'The request is missing a valid API key.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}], 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}
```

& if I were to include API key along the `request.post()` parameter I would get:

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

and if I include it after the link like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?<apiKey>
```

I would get:

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}], 'code': 400, 'message': 'Bad Request'}}
```

P.S: the doc didn't [doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#auth) even mention to include API.

Comment: How do you know your not getting access to this scope?  Did you try it? Did you add the new scope to your application and then force the user to reauthorize your application or are have you set up something in your application to request additional scopes

Comment: Not much SO users can do for you on this one, I would suggest opening a Google Support ticket to get information and a resolution.

Comment: @DalmTO please look at the updated post.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Getting in touch with google is quite impossible. Is there any specific support channel or address you would recommend? I tried Github but that didn't go anywhere either